# weak reference instantiated in another class returns nil in Swift

Tags: swift

I've been experimenting with the VIPER architecture in Swift, and it has exposed a misunderstanding I have with respect to weak references.

The following View Controller has a reference to the presenter (which is instantiated by the wireframe.

If I create the presenter from within the view controller,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var presenter: Presenter? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let presenterInst = Presenter()
        presenter = presenterInst
        print (presenter)
    }
}
```

We can print the instance of the presenter - great!

If I use the wireframe class to do the same, the instance is nil:

```
class Wireframe {
static func createViewModule (view: ViewController) {
        let presenterInst = Presenter()
         view.presenter = presenterInst
}
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var presenter: Presenter? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let presenterInst = Presenter()
        presenter = presenterInst
        print (presenter)
    }
}
```

Which is remedied by making the link to the presenter a strong reference.

So why does instantiating the var from another class mean that the instance becomes nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with "another class". An instance not retained by anything else, when assigned to a weak reference, will vanish - sooner or later. It's just that in your first code, it happens later (than when you test it).

In your second code, you test *after* `presenter` has become nil, so you actually see it.

In your first code, you don't see it, because it happens right *after* the print statement:

```
    let presenterInst = Presenter()
    presenter = presenterInst
    print (presenter) // it still _looks_ okay...
    // but _now_ code ends — and `presenter` is now nil!
```

To prove this to yourself, allow some time to elapse (using my `delay` utility):

```
    let presenterInst = Presenter()
    presenter = presenterInst
    delay(1) {
        print (presenter) // nil
    }
```

Comment: Also make sure you test in a real project, not in a playground! In a playground, memory management does not work the way it does in the real world, so the vanishing of the weak referenced instance might never happen.